# Performance issues when running stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, inner-join, database-performance

I am running a store procedure which is taking a lot of time , due to which i have to increase the timeout to nearly 3 minutes, can any one provide assistance on how i can decrease the time for the store procedure to execute , it works fine on 100-500 codes but when the code exceeds to somehow 20000 , it slows up and takes upto 3-4 minutes , below is the sp, can anyone help me optimizing it.

```
@GUID uniqueidentifier
-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT     
        COUNT(Code.allocatedVendorID) AS Amt, 
        MIN(Code.dateAllocated) AS dateAllocated, 
        derivedtbl_1.startID, derivedtbl_2.endID, 
        tbVendor.name, 
        Code.unitCost, Code.isFree, Code.isAcademic, 
        Code.isVoided, Code.GUID, Code.expiryDate
FROM         
       Code 
        INNER JOIN
              (SELECT     MIN(CodeID) AS startID, GUID
                FROM          Code AS tbAccessCode_1
                GROUP BY GUID) AS derivedtbl_1 
                ON Code.GUID = derivedtbl_1.GUID 
        INNER JOIN
              (SELECT     MAX(accessCodeID) AS endID, GUID
                FROM          Code AS tbAccessCode_1
                GROUP BY GUID) AS derivedtbl_2 
                ON Code.GUID = derivedtbl_2.GUID 
        INNER JOIN  tbVendor 
            ON Code.allocatedVendorID = tbVendor.vendorID
WHERE     (Code.GUID = @GUID) AND (Code.allocatedVendorID > 0)
GROUP BY
        derivedtbl_1.startID, derivedtbl_2.endID, 
        tbVendor.name, 
        Code.unitCost, Code.isFree, Code.isAcademic, 
        Code.isVoided, Code.GUID, Code.expiryDate

ORDER BY dateAllocated DESC
```

Comment: What indexes do you have in place?

Comment: code and vendorID is the index

Comment: Multiple subqueries have the potential to dramatically impact performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to eliminate too many scans of Code table:

```
   SELECT     COUNT(Code.allocatedVendorID) AS Amt, 
              MIN(Code.dateAllocated) AS dateAllocated,      
              Code.startID, 
              Code.endID, 
              tbVendor.name, 
              Code.unitCost, Code.isFree, Code.isAcademic, 
              Code.isVoided, Code.GUID, Code.expiryDate
    FROM         
      (select Code.*,
            min(accessCodeID) over (partition by Code.GUID) startID,
            max(accessCodeID) over (partition by Code.GUID) endID
      from Code
      where (Code.GUID = @GUID) AND (Code.allocatedVendorID > 0)
      ) Code
    INNER JOIN
          tbVendor ON Code.allocatedVendorID = tbVendor.vendorID  
    GROUP BY  Code.startID, 
              Code.endID, 
              tbVendor.name, 
              Code.unitCost, Code.isFree, Code.isAcademic, 
              Code.isVoided, Code.GUID, Code.expiryDate
    ORDER BY dateAllocated DESC
```

Comment: The nesting of the OVER columns here avoids the errors I generated. This is the correct answer

Comment: Column 'Code.GUID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @MrA It appears to be in the GROUP BY. Probably you missed something from the query...

Comment: the query is working gr8 but the start and end ID's are same :(

Comment: they are the same because the inner query contains for both min, by mistake. I'll update the answer.

Comment: thnx , even i forgot to look at that :) , thnx a lot

Comment: The issue is its just giving startid and lastid overall i need start and endid for each code.GUID